# How do I get more info for 'invalid format' error with onpladm on Windows?

Tags: batch-file, informix

This is my first time trying to use Informix. I have around 160 tables to load, using pipe-delimited text files.  We have an older series of batch files that a previous developer wrote to load Informix data, but they're not working with the new version of Informix (11.5) that I installed. I'm running it on a Windows 2003 server.

I've modified the batch file to execute the onpladm commands for one file, so this batch file looks like this:

```
onpladm create project dif31US-1-table-Load

onpladm create object -F diffdbagidaxsid.dev
onpladm create object -F diffdbagidaxsid.fmt
onpladm create object -F diffdbagidaxsid.map
onpladm create object -F diffdbagidaxsid.job
```

When I run this, it successfully creates the project and device array,
but I get an error creating the format.  The only error I get is:

```
Create object DELIMITEDFORMAT   diffile1fmt failed!
Invalid format!
```

The diffdbagidaxsid.fmt file is as follows:

```
BEGIN OBJECT DELIMITEDFORMAT diffile1fmt

PROJECT dif31US-1-table-Load
CHARACTERSET ASCII
RECORDSTART
RECORDEND
FIELDSTART
FIELDEND
FIELDSEPARATOR |
BEGIN SEQUENCE
FIELDNAME agid
FIELDTYPE Chars
END SEQUENCE
BEGIN SEQUENCE
FIELDNAME axsid
FIELDTYPE Chars
END SEQUENCE

END OBJECT
```

As you can see, it is only 2 columns.  It originally had nothing following the CHARACTERSET.  I've tried it with ASCII, and with the numeric code for ASCII, and still get the same error.

Is there any way to get a more verbose error message?

Also, can anyone recommend a decent (meaning active community) forum for Informix? I've tried the old comp.databases.informix forum, http://www.dbforums.com, the 'official' forum on IBM DeveloperWorks, and here of course. None have very much activity. We have to do this testing because we have customers (or maybe just 1 big one) who uses it, so we have to test our data and API against it.

Comment: The IIUG (International Informix User Group) web site http://www.iiug.org/ allows you to join (free, and you don't get too much obnoxious email from joining) and sign up for the mailing lists.  The ids@iiug.org mailing list is the most active and probably the relevant one to ask.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I tried to register there and haven't gotten a response after several days

Answer (score 0):

Succinctly, I don't think there is a way to get much more information out of onpladm.